# Plot many categories

Tags: r, statistics, methodology

I've data as follow, each experiment lead to the apparition of a composition, and each composition belong to one or many categories. I want to plot occurence number of each composition:

```
DF <- read.table(text = " Comp         Category

Comp1             1
Comp2             1   
Comp3             4,2
Comp4             1,3
Comp1             1,2
Comp3             3 ", header = TRUE)

barplot(table(DF$Comp))
```

So this worked perfectly for me.

After that, as composition belong to one or many categories. there's comma separations between categories.I Want to barplot the compo in X and nb of compo in Y, and for each bar the % of each category.

My Idea was to duplicate the line where there is comma, so to repete it N+1 the number of comma.

```
DF = table(DF$Category,DF$Comp)
cats <- strsplit(rownames(DF), ",", fixed = TRUE)
DF <- DF[rep(seq_len(nrow(DF)), sapply(cats, length)),]
DF <- as.data.frame(unclass(DF))
DF$cat <- unlist(cats)
DF <- aggregate(. ~ cat, DF, FUN = sum)
```

it will give me  for example: for Comp1

```
          1     2     3     4
Comp1     2     1     0     0
```

But If I apply this method, the total number of category (3) won't correspond to the total number of compositions (comp1=2).

How to proceed in such case ? is the solution is to devide by the nb of comma +1 ? if yes, how to do this in my code, and is there a simpliest way ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: basically, you want the plot that you already created, but each of the bars should have several colours that correspond to the percentage of the appearances of a given Comp that are of a given category. Or am I wrong about this? Even if I should be right, I'm still not sure what to plot. It seems that for `Comp1`, the height of the bar should still be two. But what are the percentages? 67% for 1 and 33% for 2? Or something else?

Comment: Exactly, the height of the bar of comp1 should be 2 and I should have 67% for 1 and 33% for 2. This is exactly my question and I don't know what type of plot or operation to do to my matrix. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing your plot requires two steps, as you already noticed. First, one needs to prepare the data, then one can create the plot.

### Preparing the data

You have already shown your efforts of bringing the data to a suitable form, but let me propose an alternative way.

First, I have to make sure that the `Category` column of the data frame is a character and not a factor. I also store a vector of all the categories that appear in the data frame:

```
DF$Category <- as.character(DF$Category)
cats <- unique(unlist(strsplit(DF$Category, ",")))
```

I then need to summarise the data. For this purpose, I need a function that gives for each value in `Comp` the percentage for each category scaled such, that the sum of values gives the number of rows in the original data with that `Comp`.

The following function returns this information for the entire data frame in the form of another data frame (the output needs to be a data frame, because I want to use the function with `do()` later).

```
cat_perc <- function(cats, vec) {
  # percentages
  nums <- sapply(cats, function(cat) sum(grepl(cat, vec)))
  perc <- nums/sum(nums)
  final <- perc * length(vec)
  df <- as.data.frame(as.list(final))
  names(df) <- cats
  return(df)
}
```

Running the function on the complete data frame gives:

```
cat_perc(cats, DF$Category)
##          1         4        2        3
## 1 2.666667 0.6666667 1.333333 1.333333
```

The values sum up to six, which is indeed the total number of rows in the original data frame.

Now we want to run that function for each value of `Comp`, which can be done using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
plot_data <-
group_by(DF, Comp) %>%
  do(cat_perc(cats, .$Category))
plot_data
## plot_data
## Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
## Groups: Comp [4]
## 
##     Comp        1         4         2         3
##   (fctr)    (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
## 1  Comp1 1.333333 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000
## 2  Comp2 1.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
## 3  Comp3 0.000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
## 4  Comp4 0.500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
```

This first groups the data by `Comp` and then applies the function `cat_perc` to only the subset of the data frame with a given `Comp`.

I will plot the data with the `ggplot2` package, which requires the data to be in the so-called long format. This means that each data point to be plotted should correspond to a row in the data frame. (As it is now, each row contains 4 data points.) This can be done with the `tidyr` package as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
plot_data <-  gather(plot_data, Category, value, -Comp)
head(plot_data)
## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## Groups: Comp [4]
## 
##     Comp Category    value
##   (fctr)    (chr)    (dbl)
## 1  Comp1        1 1.333333
## 2  Comp2        1 1.000000
## 3  Comp3        1 0.000000
## 4  Comp4        1 0.500000
## 5  Comp1        4 0.000000
## 6  Comp2        4 0.000000
```

As you can see, there is now a single data point per row, characterised by `Comp`, `Category` and the corresponding `value`.

### Plotting the data

Now that everything is read, we can plot the data using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Comp, y = value, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]